# What webmail provider traffic is Google Analytics talking about?

Tags: google-analytics

I received this alert in Google Analytics - I'm not running an email campaign and am not sure what emails are linking to my site. But this alert says there is "a lot" of traffic from webmail providers. Cool!

So, **where in Google Analytics can I find this traffic (I didn't see an Audience/Acquisition source like "webmail"), and what else can I learn about this traffic?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It mostly comes under the referral report, and will show the source as something  like mail.yahoo.com and mail.google.com